# Qt - Extracting words with the first letter in uppercase from a QString

Tags: qt, qstring

I have a long `QString` named `text`, and I am looking to extract all the words in it, which have their first letter in uppercase. Is there any way to use the `QString::split()` method to test each word separately ? Or even a way to do it without having to split `text` ?

Comment: Regular expression. In Qt you can use QRegularExpression class for example. To create your expression I suggest https://regex101.com/ online regexp editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
QString text = "Text is long. Or maybe longer. Yay!";
QRegularExpression regexp("[A-Z][^A-Z]*");
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator match = regexp.globalMatch(text);
QVector<QString> vec;

while(match.hasNext())
    vec.append(match.next().capturedTexts());
```

The regular expression matches everything from an upper case letter forward until next capital letter. Then since you wanted all the matches you iterate through them and save them to `QVector<QString>` (or `QStringList` if you so wish though it is discouraged to use).

Answer (score 0):

Without splitting:

```
QRegExp rx("\\b[A-Z]\\w+\\b"); // Or "\\b[A-Z]\\w*\\b"  if you want to include  one-character words

int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(text, pos)) != -1) 
{
    QString your_word = rx.cap(); // every word is here
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Comment: `QRegExp` is obsolete and is part of Qt only for backward compatibility. It should not be used in new code...